# android how to draw circles ,rectangles on canvas?

Tags: android

In my app i am able to draw something on canvas within on touch event.

But problem is, at a time single item can be draw within touch event. means if i will put lineto() and moveto() then it ll draw lines.
if addCircle() ll given then circle drawn.and also for Rect and oval.

But i want to give different buttons for that. By default line will be drawn. If i press Circle then circle will drawn, if Rect button press then Rectangle will draw on canvas by using same touch event.

So i want to know what i ll write under on touch events so that it will work for every button click?
Give me a way.
Thank you

Comment: Have done any stuff to change the color of each drawing item like line or circle or what ever? if yes, than reply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//THESE ARE GLOBAL!
boolean isDrawing = false;
boolean circle = true; //default
boolean rect = false;
boolean line = false;
```

---

Create three buttons:

```
Button circleB,rectB,lineB;
```

---

In circleB (onClick):

```
boolean circle = true; //set circle to true
boolean rect = false;
boolean line = false;
```

---

In rectB (onClick):

```
boolean circle = false;
boolean rect = true; //set rect to true
boolean line = false;
```

---

In lineB (onClick):

```
boolean circle = false; 
boolean rect = false;
boolean line = true; //set line to true
```

---

For circle size:

```
//Global
int size = 10; //Default:
boolean isScaling=false;
```

---

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent e) {
switch(e.getAction()){
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        isScaling=true;
    break;
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        if(isScaling){
            size++; //increment as you want
        }
    break;
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        isScaling=false;
        if(!isDrawing){
            isDrawing=true;
            if(circle)
            {
                //code to Draw Circle
            }
            else if(rect)
            {
                //code to Draw Rect
            }
            else if(line)
            {
                //code to Draw line
            }
            isDrawing=false;
        }
        //reset size I think it is better to reset it
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I did like this only but its not working properly. Is there any other way?

Comment: I edited and added `boolean isDrawing` .can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: One more thing i want to know every time the circle radius is same so same size of circle drawn there. But i want if i touch and move then the circle size will increase and if touch up then last size circle will appear there. How can i do it?

Comment: actually key dispatch exception came

Comment: Thanks its working.Small to big all circles are visible there.I want only last one circle how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you are talking about. But if I do it could be done with canvas.drawCircle, canvas.drawRect methods.

Comment: Ya i know. i am using path. and in path for line path.lineto() & path.moveto() is there. For circle path.addcircle() is there. But I want to know how can i add differently on a button click?

Comment: means for Touch_down , touch_move, & touch_up is there na? So if i ll write path.lineto(), path.moveto(), path.addcircle(), then it ll at a time add. But I want if i press circle button then it will draw only cicle not line